# C# Boolean set by event not working

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean, itext, flags

I have a problem with boolean set by event.

```
private void HandlePageStart(Document document, PdfWriter writer)
{
    ItemsTableColumnHeadersInsertNeeded = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Page started");
}
```

The HandlePageStart function is fired by event and it works just fine and sets boolean to true. However if statement running in the loop in another function doesn't work and the code inside the if statement is never executed.

```
private void AddItemsToTable(Invoice inv, PdfPTable table)
{
    foreach (InvoiceItem item in inv.Items)
    {
         ...add content to page...

         if (ItemsTableColumnHeadersInsertNeeded)
         {
             AddItemsTableColumnsHeaders(table);
             ItemsTableColumnHeadersInsertNeeded = false;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the declaration of `ItemsTableColumnHeadersInsertNeeded`. Is it even in the same class/namespace?

Comment: It's really hard to say something meaningful without understanding the entire context. Try to add more details, like where is this event being raised? Are you working muti-threaded? Is there only one instance of this class? The more details you add the higher the chances you get your answer here.

Comment: I added an answer and deleted it, I can't answer without further clarification. One quick fix to check, mark the bool as **volatile**

Comment: How are both related to each other? Is `AddItemsToTable` called definitely after your boolean is set to true and are you certain nothing happens to that boolean inbetween? This looks like some sort of a concurrency issue.

Comment: Did you mean to write headers before page content in the code? It just seems odd to write something called "header" after the first item

Comment: Is AddItemsToTable called multiple times per page?

Comment: No, AddItemsToTable is called once.

Comment: Er... is `HandlePageStart` an iText method? I don't know that method. How is this an iText question?

Comment: HandlePageStart is method fired by an iText page event.

Answer (score 0):

Things that usually cause such behavior are:

1. you have a second, local variable with the same name that gets reset every time the control flow runs over its declaration
2. there is another event that is fired and resets your variable

The first thing I would try is search for all assignments of the variable with that name (not intellisense but textual search, to get all different variables with the same name). Set a breakpoint on every assignment and see which is called in what order.